# Multiple Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to help install a third party theme onto a WordPress installation and I get these three error codes when I click "live preview" or "activate" the theme:

> Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: open(/var/chroot/home/content/66/5232766/tmp/sess_1n0eifrftmjfu96hop17kihi35, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2) in /home/content/66/5232766/html/wp-content/themes/Drlawyer/functions.php on line 461
>
> Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at /home/content/66/5232766/html/wp-content/themes/Drlawyer/functions.php:461) in /home/content/66/5232766/html/wp-content/themes/Drlawyer/functions.php on line 461
>
> Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/content/66/5232766/html/wp-content/themes/Drlawyer/functions.php:461) in /home/content/66/5232766/html/wp-content/themes/Drlawyer/functions.php on line 461

How can I fix these things?

Comment: Here is the code that is causing the problem:

`function cp_admin_init() {
 if (!session_id())
 session_start();
}`

I added this code to the above code:

`ini_set('session.save_path', 'tmp');`

Now it is giving me this error code only in the dashboard and not on the actual site:

`Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: open(tmp/sess_qrj5st7q63acsjrnsda545p6j2, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2) in /home/content/66/5232766/html/wp-content/themes/Drlawyer/functions.php on line 462`

Comment: This is another error code it is giving on Dashboard now:

`Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/content/66/5232766/html/wp-content/themes/Drlawyer/functions.php:462) in /home/content/66/5232766/html/wp-content/themes/Drlawyer/functions.php on line 462`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try commenting the line out and removing your addition

```
function cp_admin_init() // { if (!session_id()) session_start(); }
```

If this is godaddy hosting you might need to do this (I run into this problem all the time)
Add this to your php5.ini file then  you will need to kill all processes from your godaddy hosting control panel and it will work. check your phpinfo.php file to make sure it took

```
upload_tmp_dir = /var/chroot/home/content/56/10594156/html/temp
session.save_path = /var/chroot/home/content/56/10594156/html/temp
```

of course change the pathto to yours and then create a /temp dir in your root and CHMOD 777
Godaddy has issues with the tmp/ dir for some reason

Comment: Awesome this worked!

I just want to make sure I have my php.ini file correct:

`upload_tmp_dir = /home/content/66/5232766/html/temp
session.save_path = /home/content/66/5232766/html/temp`

Comment: if it worked check inside the directory /temp and see if its writing files. then look at the pathto/root on your phpinfo.php and see if it matches. either one will let you know if it worked

Comment: I don't see any files getting written. Under environment, this is what it shows:

`TEMP /var/chroot/home/content/66/5232766/tmp`

`TMPDIR /var/chroot/home/content/66/5232766/tmp`